# This map is not a vector map. That will prevent use of data-driven styling

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using data-driven styling to render my map, but when I load the page on a virtual machine under the company network I have this error:

> The map is not a vector map. That will prevent use of data-driven styling.

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95xDl.png)

[Expanded error with stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znvay.png)

This only happens on this virtual machine under the company network.
We are using ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1 and the new Advanced Markers. Both have the same issue with the map. The virtual machines were created with Hyper-V VMS

If I render on any other machine the map loads without an issue.

We even created a new virtual machine without any company configuration and we have this issue, the only thing that share is the same physical network.

Here is my mapOptions

```
            mapOptions: {
                // Center of USA lat lng as fallback default
                center: { lat: 37.0902, lng: -97.0129 },
                zoom: 4,
                styles: null,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                zoomControl: false,
                gestureHandling: 'none',
                region: 'US',
                mapId: 'private-map-id'
            },
```

Here is my call to Administrative Area 1
           `this.featureLayer = this.map.getFeatureLayer('ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1');`

I'm using Google Chrome 110.0.5481.178, Edge 110.0.1587.57, Firefox 110.0.1 and I have the same issue.

Any idea on what is happening?

Comment: Have you checked proxies/firewall rules/anti-virus/ad-blocker/etc. specific to that machine/network?  If it works elsewhere, it is likely an environment issue.

Comment: Have you reviewed [the Content Security Policy Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/content-security-policy)?

Comment: Please don't post (just) pictures of text error messages, see [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646713/google-map-is-not-recognized-as-a-vector-map-on-some-browsers